# Adding an array to a class in PHP extension

Tags: c, php-extension

I'm trying to create a PHP extension that has a class and one of the elements is supposed to be an array of strings. When I try to do it like I have below, when I uncomment my attempts to create and implement an array in `test_init_test()`, I get the error "`PHP Fatal error:  Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0`".

I'm either not understanding on how to create arrays or I'm just not understanding the `zend_declare_property` functions. How am I supposed to do this?

```
#include "php.h"
#include "php_myextension.h"
#include "test.h"

zend_class_entry *test_ce_test;

static zend_function_entry test_methods[] = {
    PHP_ME(Test, __construct, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_CTOR)

    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

void test_init_test(TSRMLS_D) {
    zend_class_entry ce;

    // zval *cachedirs_array = emalloc(sizeof(zval));
    // array_init(cachedirs_array);

    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "Test", test_methods);
    test_ce_test = zend_register_internal_class(&ce TSRMLS_CC);

    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "arch", sizeof("arch"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    // zend_declare_property(test_ce_test, "cachedirs", sizeof("cachedirs"), cachedirs_array, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    // zend_declare_property(test_ce_test, "cachedirs", sizeof("cachedirs"), cachedirs_array, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "dbpath", sizeof("dbpath"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "root", sizeof("root"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
}

PHP_METHOD(Test, __construct) {
    char *rootpath;
    char *dbpath;
    size_t rp, dp;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &rootpath, &rp, &dbpath, &dp) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL()
    }

    object_init_ex(return_value, test_ce_test);

    zend_update_property_stringl(test_ce_test, getThis(), "root", sizeof("root"), rootpath, rp TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_update_property_stringl(test_ce_test, getThis(), "dbpath", sizeof("dbpath"), dbpath, dp TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare an empty zval then update it with an array in the constructor.

```
void test_init_test(TSRMLS_D) {
    zend_class_entry ce;

    zval *cd = (zval*)malloc(sizeof(zval)); /* empty zval */

    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "Test", test_methods);
    test_ce_test = zend_register_internal_class(&ce TSRMLS_CC);

    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "arch", sizeof("arch"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_declare_property(test_ce_test, "cachedirs", sizeof("cachedirs"), cd, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC); /* declare with empty zval */
    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "dbpath", sizeof("dbpath"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_declare_property_string(test_ce_test, "root", sizeof("root"), "", ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_CC);
}

PHP_METHOD(Test, __construct) {
    char *rootpath;
    char *dbpath;
    size_t rp, dp;

    /* create zval */
    zval cd;

    /* init array */
    array_init(&cd);

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &rootpath, &rp, &dbpath, &dp) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL()
    }

    object_init_ex(return_value, test_ce_test);

    /* update property with new array */
    zend_update_property(alpm_ce_handle, getThis(), "cachedirs", sizeof("cachedirs") - 1, &cd TSRMLS_CC);

    zend_update_property_stringl(test_ce_test, getThis(), "root", sizeof("root"), rootpath, rp TSRMLS_CC);
    zend_update_property_stringl(test_ce_test, getThis(), "dbpath", sizeof("dbpath"), dbpath, dp TSRMLS_CC);
}
```